# PDFtk and number formatted PDF form field

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox, pdftk

I'm using [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) to fill in the form with the generated fdf.

In the PDF form, the form field is configured as a number field with 2 decimal point, and the negative value will be showing with parentheses, for example, **-4444** will become **(4444.00)**

Using any PDF viewers and changing the value on form did make the form display the value correctly with the behaviour explained above (negative value will become value with parentheses)

Tested also with the FDF (by importing to the form), the negative value will be displayed correctly as well.

But when using the pdftk fill-form action, the negative value remains as it is without changing the display, which is still showing -4444 and not (4444.00)

Is anyone experienced this before / has a solution for this?

#### Update #1

I've also tested [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), it has the same issue :(
And now I'm trying to achieve this by using the PDF's javascript, any clue that this way will works?

#### Update #2

came across this thread [How to refresh Formatting on Non-Calculated field and refresh Calculated fields in Fillable PDF form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093162/how-to-refresh-formatting-on-non-calculated-field-and-refresh-calculated-fields/16903682#16903682) and so gave it a try with iText as well. However still unable to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i've found some ways to get the formatting works in the PDF form fields.

## Approach #1

#### Requirements

1. pdftk
2. PDF form with javascript

In the PDF, create a "Document Javascript" [(see how)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307556/adobe-acrobat-pro-xi-adding-javascript-to-a-pdf?answertab=votes#tab-top) and re-assign the form's value to make it dirty as mentioned by Denis in the thread of Update #2. The script could be as simple as below:

```
var text1 = this.getField('text1');
text1.value = text1.value;
```

#### Downside

Javascript will only be triggered when you open the PDF, and if you would like to set the PDF with some ownerPassword to prevent user edit the file, the javascript will just failed because of read-only form fields. Otherwise, imagine you have 100 form fields in the PDF, re-assign each of them is a nightmare.

## Approach #2

1. iText
2. PDF form

I personally will prefer this approach. The powerful iText already has the API to set the form field and at the same time formatting the field display [(see how)](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/filling-out-forms#1173-formatfields.java). The generated PDF is ready to print as well with the correct format.

#### Downside

Either using the iText API to find out the existing format of the form field, or you will hard code the format in your codes. Require more efforts than using the pdftk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a simpler version of ChinKang's #1.

In Tools -> Document Javascripts:

```
this.calculateNow();
```

One thing to check is in Tools -> Set field calculation order that any calculations are ordered appropriately.

I then use https://github.com/ccnmtl/fdfgen and pdftk to fill the forms in.

The only gotcha is that you cannot flatten the PDF